# Swift/SpriteKit - When to use multiple ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So this might be a stupid question, but I'm relatively new to *Swift* and *spritekit*.

What's the difference between using multiple scenes with one `ViewController` and multiple `ViewController`s? 
Until now I've always used one `ViewController` and simply jumped between scenes.

Why should I use one or the other?
And when to use multiple `ViewController`s?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question outside of SO? I have the same question and trying to understand the pluses/minuses of different approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might allow you to keep your view controller swift file size down and separated amongs different files. So it is easier to read.